# Where do apps like zite get their feeds from?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, parsing, mobile

I notice that apps like Zite show articles with full text and images, but if you go onto any of these sites' RSS feeds, they only have maybe a summary of the text, and an article title. Is zite parsing the content from the actual webpages, or is it using a special feed? If it's parsing from webpages, is it legal to include that functionality in an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is Full Site RSS, and as you've guessed, those feeds come from services that scrape sites.  http://fulltextrssfeed.com/ is one (free) service.  I'm sure a Google search will reveal others.